# Git remote as local

Tags: git, git-gui

My web host has installed Git as "client" on their Linux-based (I believe Debian) web hosting servers, not as "server".

Is there a way to use GitGUI via my Windows 7 desktop computer to connect to Git installation of my web host?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's *almost* no distinction between "client" and "server" Git installations: Git provides exactly one program which is able to serve Git repositories by itself — `git-daemon`. And as it provides no authentication, it's usually only installed on machines which serve publicly-accessible repositories (using the free-for-all read-only `git://` protocol).

All the "usual" write access to Git repositories is *mediated* by other software — typically a `HTTP[S]` server (for `http://` protocol) or `SSH` server (for `ssh://` protocol).  This software performs the necessary authentication and authorization and then calls a low-level Git program to carry out the client/server data exchange.

So you should decide how you want to access your repositories first.

In your circumstances I would opt for SSH: as your web host is (supposedly) a Linux-powered VPS, it most probably has SSH server already up and running, and you should have been given an account for this (if not, there's the time to ask).

The rest of the story is explained [here](http://nathanj.github.com/gitguide/index.html) (with nice pictures). The only difference for you is that since you won't be using github, you will have to manually transfer your public SSH key to your VPS host.

More info on hosting Git on the server as usually [is available in The Book](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-on-the-Server) (with [this](http://git-scm.com/2010/03/04/smart-http.html) being a later-time addendum regarding the improved `HTTP[S]` support in Git).

**Update** on using SSH with Git.

In fact, hosting a Git repository accessed over SSH might be both dead simple or complicated depending on what you're setting up — a simple solution or a high-profile server with virtualized Git users and access rights management etc.

Using SSH, Git works this way:

1. The client performs SSH connection with the SSH server process running on the machine hosting the target Git repo.  Usually this is done using the so-called pubkey authentication.
2. After the connection is established, the client tells the other side to spawn a special Git process which then talks to the local Git process, and SSH carries out their exchange — authenticated and encrypted.

There are two other bits which are essential to master to let us move further:

- While SSH supports several "services" (for instance, SFTP — a secure version of FTP, and making plain TCP tunnels), the most common use case for it is starting a process remotely, and in the most common case it's a shell (that's why it's named SSH after all — a Secure SHell).

  When such a remote process is started it works with the credentials of the logged in user. So when *you* log into an SSH server — either "by hand" or Git does this for you — a shell is started on the remote server, and it works with the credentials of the *remote* user which you authenticated as.
- Before trying to access a remote repository the Git client parses the URL of that repository. The gory details are in the [`git-fetch` manual](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-fetch.html#URLS) but the simple thing is that an URL like

  ```
  ssh://user@server/path/to/the/repo.git
  ```

  is broken down to the protocol part, the user, the server and the path to the repository, which is

  ```
  /path/to/the/repo.git
  ```

  This path to the repo is a physical path on the server. So yes, it's that simple: you do not have to tweak some sort of config file or so to tell Git where the repo is, instead, you just speficy it in your URL.

  A somewhat advanced twist of the repository path handling is that it's possible to use a special shortcut to refer to the home directory of the remote user.  This is done using the path like

  ```
  /~/devel/repo.git
  ```

  Which makes Git to look for the directory named "devel" under the home directory of the remote user and then look for the "repo.git" directory in there.  This approach is useful if you do not want to set aside a special directory to keep Git repositories.  Also this approach is ideal for one-man projects.

  On a typical Linux-based OS, users have their home directories under the `/home` hierarchy, so that a user `johndoe` has `/home/johndoe` as their home directory. After logging in interactively via SSH you can verify what's your home directory is by doing

  ```
  cd
  pwd
  ```

  (the first command changes the current directory to the home directory and the second one prints the current directory).

So, for the simplest case you could do just this:

1. Log into the server via SSH.
2. Create a server-side repository somewhere:

   ```
   cd /var/tmp
   mkdir test.git
   cd test.git
   git init --bare
   ```
3. Log out.
4. Add this remote to your local repository:

   ```
   git remote add test ssh://user@server/var/tmp/test.git
   ```
5. Work with this remote:

   ```
   git push test master
   ```

To verify Git works OK on the server, just try something like

```
ssh user@server "git --version"
```

or

```
plink user@server "git --version"
```

if you're using PuTTY and not the OpenSSH client shipped with Git for Windows.

Comment: Hi @kostix and thanks for your answer. I have read through the guide by NathanJ and came short, even though it is a great article; I am not a Linux or Git or SSH expert; I have had very little experience with it. I have been given SSH access, and I have found a guide to generate the SSH keys a while back, and have generated my key. My biggest problem is that GitGUI asks for a physical directory path to connect to, it seems, not ssh://. I will play around more. In the mean time I will upvote your answer, thanks!

Comment: @KobusMyburgh, I've updated my answer to write up on using SSH.

Comment: You might want to check out gitosis (https://github.com/tv42/gitosis), it handles all the user managment in git for you.

Comment: @dtech, well, yes, but a) I'd go for [`gitolite`](https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite) instead (the project isn't dormant, is deployed in some high-profile places, that author is active on the Git list), and b) I intended to try to make Kobus actually understand what happens behind the scenes when SSH is involved.

Comment: @KobusMyburgh, as to `git gui` asking for a physical path -- I think you're not correct as it's asking for a Git URL, so you should figure out what URL you should use and then feed it to the `git gui`. Or just add a named remote using Git commands (as I showed in my answer) and `git gui` will pick up your new named remote automatically (as it uses the same repository settings).

Comment: Thanks, @kostix I appreciate it.I will look through gitolite as well, and work through your post. I have since accepted your answer, but I still need to work through it. I believe it will work :-) Thanks!